# How to play a sound using pygame in all Operating System?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, pygame

I have written a python script to play sound.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame
import time
def playNotificationSount():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("notification.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(10)
playNotificationSount()
```

It can play sound fine in ubuntu but no sound is played in windows. It gives no error message. 
How can I improve the script so that it can play sound in all OS?

Comment: I don't know why the music isn't playing on Windows, but pygame is known to have problems with mp3 files, so I'd recommend to convert it into the .ogg format and see if that works. Also, keep in mind that mp3 is a proprietary format and you can be forced to pay license fees if you use it in your game.

Comment: I tried ogg file but result is same. No sound in windows.

Comment: Can you play the file in another audio player in Windows?

Comment: @skrx yes I can.

Comment: I forgot to ask if that's really all of your code. I think you have to call `pygame.display.set_mode()` (to open a pygame window) before the music or sound can be played. Also, calling `pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)` before `pygame.init()` can help sometimes.

Comment: Yes, this is really all of my code. Nothing more needed in ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play a sound (or music) without opening a pygame window, you have to call [`pygame.mixer.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init) before you call `pygame.init()` (or call only `pygame.mixer.init()`). The reason why you have to do this is not clear to me, but it works. Here's a minimal example:

```
import pygame


pygame.mixer.init()  # Initialize the mixer module.
sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('notification.mp3')  # Load a sound.

while True:
    inpt = input('Press enter to play the sound: ')
    sound1.play()  # Play the sound.
    print('Playing sound')
```

In a normal game you have to call `pygame.display.set_mode()` to open a pygame window before the music or sound can be played and you don't have to call `pygame.mixer.init()` separately. Also, calling `pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)` before `pygame.init()` can help if something is wrong with the sound.

```
import pygame


pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

def playNotificationSound():
    pygame.mixer.music.load('notification.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

playNotificationSound()
```